# R plot() produces date labels in Russian

Tags: r, datetime, plot, locale

I'm working on a machine with Russian Win 8.1.

While installing RStudio I chose English as default language, but when dealing with dates (POSIXt), `plot()` gives me an output with Russian labels on the time axis.

How can I fix it? I want English.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You have to deal with your locales: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html.

Comment: It also worked for me to change the sysem locale in windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on a comment from [Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3710546/pascal), the answer for the question is to set locale

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "english")
```

Another option is to change the locale of OS.